# Problem with setting up mock for all unit tests in Vitest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, next.js, vitest

I've only recently begun experimenting with vitest, but I've already reached the walll. I've setup my mock successfully in `my.test.ts` file

```
// THIS IS WORKING WITHOUT ANY ISSUES
vi.mock("./getCashedDatasapceToken", () => {
  return {
    getCashedDatasapceToken: () => {
      return {
        access_token: getTokenResponse.access_token,
        expires_in: "2030-03-20",
      };
    },
  };
});

describe("fetchAutocompleteSuggestions", () => {
  it("should return autocomplete suggestions for searchText = 'online'", async () => {
    const response = await fetchAutocompleteSuggestions("online");
    expect(response).toEqual(fetchAutocompleteResponse);
  });
});
```

but I want to use my mocked function in other test files. I know that it's possible to do it inside the setupFiles of vitest. Unfortunately I had no luck.

I've tried many things in my setup file, like putting a mocked function to *beforeAll*, setting up *globals *in *defineConfig*, etc.

Here is my configuration:

```
//vitest.config.ts
export default defineConfig({
  test: {
    globals: true,
    setupFiles: ["tests-config/setup-tests.ts"],
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": path.resolve(__dirname, "./src"),
    },
  },
});
```

```
// setup-tests.ts
beforeEach(() => {
  vi.mock("./getCashedDatasapceToken", () => {
    return {
      getCashedDatasapceToken: () => {
        return {
          access_token: getTokenResponse.access_token,
          expires_in: "2030-03-20",
        };
      },
    };
  });
});

beforeAll(() => server.listen());
afterEach(() => {
  server.resetHandlers();
  vi.restoreAllMocks();
});
afterAll(() => server.close());
```

What am I missing?!